# How can I type argument when it could be different object type in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a function that renders me some inputs that I receive dynamically from backend

I've added types for all of them like this:

```
interface TPField {
  // CRM id as a hash.
  id: string
  name: string
  label: string
  readonly: boolean
  disabled: boolean
  value: string
  type: string
}

/**
 * Interface for base field with text field.
 */
export interface TPTextField extends TPField {
  autocomplete: boolean
  autofocus: boolean
  placeholder: string
  required: boolean
  maxlength: number
}

/**
 * Interface for input type number field.
 */
export interface TPNumberField extends TPTextField {
  min: {
    enabled: boolean
    value: number
  }
  max: {
    enabled: boolean
    value: number
  }
  step: number
}

/**
 * Interface for input type checkbox field.
 */
export interface TPCheckboxField extends TPField {
  checked: boolean
}

export interface TPRadioField extends TPField {
  checked: boolean
}

/**
 * Interface for select field.
 */
export interface TPSelectField extends TPField {
  multiple: boolean
  options: TPSelectFieldOption[]
}

/**
 * Interface for a single option for select field.
 */
export interface TPSelectFieldOption {
  disabled: boolean
  label: string
  value: string
}
```

And I've typed function arguments via Union types, but it throws an error that these properties doesn't exist on this type. I've also tried to type it like `Record<string, unknown>` but it didn't help me either. Didn't get what am I doing wrong.

```
const renderInput = ({
    checked,
    name,
    label,
    options,
    placeholder,
    type,
    value,
  }:
    | TPCheckboxField
    | TPNumberField
    | TPSelectField
    | TPSelectFieldOption
    | TPTextField
    | TPField) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'text':
        return (
          <StyledFormItem name={name}>
            <Input defaultValue={value} type='text' placeholder={placeholder} />
          </StyledFormItem>
        )
      case 'number':
        return (
          <StyledFormItem name={name}>
            <Input defaultValue={value} type='number' />
          </StyledFormItem>
        )
      case 'checkbox':
        return (
          <StyledFormItem name={name} valuePropName='checked'>
            <Checkbox checked={checked}>{label}</Checkbox>
          </StyledFormItem>
        )
      case 'select':
        return (
          <StyledFormItem name={name}>
            <Select options={options} />
          </StyledFormItem>
        )
    }
  }
```

I'm getting
`Property 'all propreties except value and label' does not exist on type 'TPField | TPCheckboxField | TPNumberField | TPTextField | TPSelectField | TPSelectFieldOption'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was to go with separate interface

```
interface Inputs {
  checked: boolean
  name: string
  label: string
  options: TPSelectFieldOption[]
  placeholder: string
  type: string
  value: string | number
}
```

and then pass it to the function like `Partial<Inputs>`